# Infinite scroll pagination with a Wookmark layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

```
/* Infinite Scroll Pagination with a Wookmark layout
 *
 * Requires: jQuery, Wookmark
 */

var myApp = myApp || {};

;(function(myApp,$){
  var WookmarkPagination = function(elem, options){
    this.elem = elem;
    this.$elem = $(elem);
    this.options = options;
  };

  WookmarkPagination.prototype = {
    defaults: {
      url: '',
      page: 2,
      per_page: 5,
      template: '',
      scroll: true,
      item: ".item",
      items: ".items",
      loader_image: ''
    },

    fetchReady: {
      status: true
    },

    /**
     * Initiate app. Bind the scroll event and onScroll function to the document.
     *
     * @return this
     */
    init: function(){
      var _this = this;
      _this.config = $.extend({}, _this.defaults, _this.options);
      var loader = '<div id="wookmark-pagination-loader"><img src="'+_this.config.loader_image+'" alt="Loading..." /></div>';

      // Set loader
      $(loader).appendTo("body").hide();

      // Build wookmark layout
      wookmark_handler = this.$elem.find(_this.config.item);
      wookmark_handler.wookmark({
        container: _this.$elem,
        offset: 15,
        itemWidth: 160,
        autoResize: true
      });

      if(_this.config.scroll){
        $(document).bind('scroll', function(){
          _this.onScroll();
        });
      }
      return _this;
    },

    /**
     * Rebuild Wookmark layout
     *
     * @return void
     */
    refreshLayout: function(){
      var _this = this;
      var opt = _this.config;
      //console.log(wookmark_handler);

      // Rebuild wookmark positions
      if(wookmark_handler) wookmark_handler.wookmarkClear();
      wookmark_handler = _this.$elem.find(_this.config.item);

      // Initialize Wookmark to build layout container
      wookmark_handler.wookmark({
        container: _this.$elem,
        offset: 15,
        itemWidth: 160,
        autoResize: true
      });
    },

    /**
     * Fetches the JSON from the server. On success rebuilds Wookmark positioning.
     *
     * @return the JSON object
     */
    fetch: function(){
      var _this = this;
      var opt = _this.config;

      // If no other getJSON is being processed continue
      if(_this.fetchReady.status){
        // Block other requests
        _this.fetchReady.status = false;

        // Show loader
        $("#wookmark-pagination-loader").fadeIn();

        // Fetch Data
        return $.getJSON(opt.url,{
          page: opt.page,
          per_page: opt.per_page
        })
        .success(function(data){
          // Each data item is wrapped in a template and appended to the page.
          $.each(data, function(i, item){
            _this.$elem.find(_this.config.items).append(Mustache.to_html(opt.template, item.item));
          });

          // Set next page number for next request.
          opt.page += 1;

          _this.refreshLayout();

        })
        // TODO: setup error catching and show a user there was a problem with the request
        //.error(function(data, response){})
        .complete(function(data){
          // Allow other getJSON requests
          _this.fetchReady.status = true;

          // Hide loader
          $("#wookmark-pagination-loader").fadeOut();
        });
      }
    },

    /**
     * Checks if the scroll position has reached the bottom, then runs the fetch function
     *
     * @return void
     */
    onScroll: function() {
      // Check if we're within 100 pixels of the bottom edge of the broser window.
      var closeToBottom = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100);
      if(closeToBottom) {
        this.fetch();
      }
    }
  };

  WookmarkPagination.defaults = WookmarkPagination.prototype.defaults;

  $.fn.wookmark_pagination = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      new WookmarkPagination(this, options).init();
    });
  };

  myApp.WookmarkPagination = WookmarkPagination;
})(myApp,jQuery);
```

Comment: What is a Wookmark layout?

Comment: Looks okay as per my review, no problem at all.. it will be better if you can give us a sample how actually you are using

Answer (score 2):

The code looks pretty good, but here are a couple suggestions:

- The semicolon at the top is unnecessary: `;(function(myApp,$){`
- You use `_this` in many places where `this` would work:

  - Consider Function.bind ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), only works on modern browsers)
  - This very much depends on personal style
- This is a little confusing. I don't write jQuery much, but it isn't clear what the first `this` is referring to (and the second this has a different meaning than the one above, which is also confusing):

  ```
  $.fn.wookmark_pagination = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      new WookmarkPagination(this, options).init();
    });
  };
  ```

Comment: `this` references `jQuery` iirc. Its standard for this type of code. Definitely agree there is no need for both `this` and `_this` in most places and is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Use jslint to fix all warnings . It is not necessary, but sometimes helpful.
There are some bad things, like using `var`s without declaration and so on, and also bad formatting (can use jsmin to format JavaScript). I'd also add `$(document)` and `$(window)` as argument to plugin and use them inside plugin.

There are also many common thing that you repeat:

```
$("#wookmark-pagination-loader").fadeOut();
```

Push `$("#wookmark-pagination-loader")` to plugin like argument or cache it in `var` and make method, that will show and hide loading.

Also, each block of code after comment you can substitute with a function call:

```
// Build wookmark layout
wookmark_handler = this.$elem.find(self.config.item);
    wookmark_handler.wookmark({
    container : self.$elem,
    offset : 15,
    itemWidth : 160,
    autoResize : true
});

function builtWookmarkLayout() {
   ... //do things here
}
```

Use some hints to make jQuery faster. Cache requests to DOM tree in variables, use pure JavaScript sometimes.

```
var loadingContainer = $(document.getElementById('wookmark-pagination-loader'));
showLoading = function () {
    this.loadingContainer.fadeIn();
}
```

For old browser, add an explicit function `create` like:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (obj) {
        function F() {};
        F.prototype = obj;
        return new F();
    }
}
```

You also use objects with exactly one field, so substitute them with `var`.

```
fetchReady : {
    status : true
}
```

Use explicit comparisons:

```
if (self.fetchReady.status === true) {...
```

I can find much more "clever" advice.  But in my opinion, it is nit-picking. It works, it's readable, it's compact, it's OK.